# Trying to build Sencha Touch demo apps on ubuntu

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm trying to build Sencha Touch demo apps on ubuntu but there is no any option to build android aap or ios app.

There is only one option for build wed app how to fix this problem.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/ try sencha doc.

Answer (score 0):

Creating mobile app using Sencha Touch is perfect.
If you want to execute the Sencha app as an android app or ios app, you can download the latest [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) library.
 Phonegap is used to package web application inside any mobile operating system e.g. android, ios, windows, tizen etc. 
You can go through the [installation procedure](http://phonegap.com/install/).
As per now you are already done with developing the Sencha Application.
 Before you wrap the SPA (Sencha App) for a mobile device. You should build the Sencha app using `sencha app build package` command under the application directory of the sencha app.

After successful build, you can find the ultimate build package inside the

> ApplicationFolder/build/package/

Files inside this app has to be used to package via phonegap. 
To create an android/ios app you have to create an app for the respective operating system under the `phonegap/Android/bin` directory. You can create a project using `create ./<ProjectName> <package name> <AppName>`. You will get a full fledge app created for ios/android. 
Inside the app you can see a `www` folder inside the WebContent where you have to copy the entire app from the build folder of Sencha Application.
You can refer a [video](https://vimeo.com/55335529)